# My habeneros have shrunk over winter!

Tags: chili, fruits, overwintering

Since we don't get frosts, I kept my chillies over winter, replanted them into beds, and most have survived very successfully. I was excited to see them flower early in spring, however the fruits turned a ripe colour much quicker than they did in their first season, and the size of each fruit is only about 1/3 of the size of the summer crop.

[image: Plants]

I cut one of the fruit in half (please excuse my blurry picture), and it looks like there is a green 'pea' in the centre, where the seeds should be. The flesh still has some heat, but they taste bitter.

[image: Inside Fruit / <code>Pea</code>]

Should I pick and discard the dwarf fruit and hope that a better crop turns out later? It looks like my jalapenos are also turning out tiny, although my other chillies haven't started flowering yet.

**Update**

After picking off all the `miniature` chillies, about 2 to 3 weeks later, new flowers fruited and the fruit is again full-sized, albeit taking much longer (5-6 weeks) to fully ripen.

A similar thing happened to my jalapenos - I had tiny jalapenos which turned red within 2 weeks of the fruit first forming.

I would still be interested to know why this happens? Early spring cold snap? Nitrogen in the soil perhaps?

Comment: for sweet peppers, both bitterness and a small size generally mean not enough water. Is that a possibility for you?

Comment: Thanks Kate - actually, we've had a really long, wet winter and spring - I can't believe that a lack of water is to blame?

Comment: Yes I've seen a wide variation with climate, of both fruit and leaf size on the same pepper plant. Having lots of fruit on a plant will limit the setting of new fruit, so I would remove them as they ripen.

Comment: harvesting will stimulate new growth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like incomplete pollination to me.  Early spring with its irregular cold snaps can sometimes interfere with pollination, even for plants that are self-fertile. There may be enough seed set to trigger fruit formation, but not enough to warrant the plant putting energy into making a full-size fruit for just a few seeds.

Comment: Thanks - as per recommendations above, I harvested the `runt` habeneros and within 6 weeks full sized fruit appeared.